# The given key was not present in the dictionary on Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#

I hope you can give me a hand on this. It's been bothering me for a quite while already. and I find no conclusive answers on the web. I have a simple class hierarchy: BaseClass with ClassA, ClassB and DefaultClass derived from it. They all have a constructor like ClassA(Input input) : base(input) ... all very simple. Now I have the following factory

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class Factory
    {

        public static Dictionary<string, Type> Map = 
        new Dictionary<string, Type>
        {
            {"ClassA", typeof(ClassA)},
            {"ClassB", typeof(ClassB)}
        };
        public static BaseClass Create(Input input)
        {
            Type constructor;
            try
            {
                constructor = Map[input.ClassType];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                constructor = typeof(DefaultClass);
            }
            return (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(constructor, input);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the .ClassType member of the input object determines what class is instantiated. This type of construct has been working for a simple call like

```
var myClass = Factory.Create(input);
```

in my standalone application. Now I must have the application running on a server and the call to the Create method receives a serialized input object from the client. I would say that's the only difference between the application that works and the one that doesn't. Now, input is something along the lines

```
[DataContract]
public class Input
{
    [DataMember] public string ClassType;
    [DataMember] public string member1;
}
```

wheras before it had no such DataContract or DataMember annotations. Well, now the the code crashed at the Activator.CreateInstance line with an exception "the given key was not present in dictionary". Do you have any clue of why this could be? The only difference is the serialized object in the constructor.

Thanks a lot in advance and regards.

Comment: You should use Dictionary.TryGetValue instead of catching the KeyNotFoundException. Exceptions are very expensive.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I don't see how the Activator.CreateInstance would throw an exception like this. It could be thrown only on the line constructor = Map[input.ClassType]

Comment: Hello the full exception, with stack trace is

Comment: Hello the original exception is: Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation. The inner Exception is: The given key was not present in the dicionary. The stack trace is (sorry I cannot edit it better in the comment section: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, RuntimeType declaringType)  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType declaringType) and it goes on (for @svick)

Comment: How is the constructor of `ClassA` and `ClassB` looks like?

Comment: @edd You can include the stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code snippets you provided should work fine. Look into your constructors of your objects. I'm sure exception is raised somewhere inside their implementation.

And I fully agree that better to use Dictionary.TryGetValue() instead of catching exception. Here is useful link to learn exceptions: [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx).